# Get Additional information in the order view payment information section

Tags: magento2

I created a payment method and added 2 fields **vendor** **name** and **vendor voucher** and save field in the database using observer.
It's working fine. Now, I want this to show additional information in the **order view payment information section**.
Any help please on how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: do you want to show in admin or frontend?

Comment: currently in admin its save from fornt end in addtional_informaton

Comment: a:3:{s:14:"voucher_number";s:5:"23423";s:11:"vendor_name";s:6:"werwrw";s:12:"method_title";s:16:"Training Vssoucher";} like that

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about payment additional information.
Assuming you have the actual order object in the variable `$order` you can get the complete array of additional information with the following code:

```
$additionalInformation = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
```

If you are in quote context, there is a similar way. Again I assume that your actual quote is in the variable `$quote`:

```
$additionalInformation = $quote->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
```

Update: In case the returned data is not an array, it might be necessary to unserialize it like follows:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$serializer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize');
$additionalInformationArray = $serializer->unserialize($additionalInformation);
//after this you can access it by key like this:
echo $additionalInformationArray['voucher_number'];
echo $additionalInformationArray['vendor_name'];
....
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: {s:14:"voucher_number";s:5:"23423";s:11:"vendor_name";s:6:"werwrw";s:12:"method_title";s:16:"Training Vssoucher";} i am getting like that after your code now i want voucher_number and vendor name form here;)

Comment: I hope the complete output you get is `a:3:{s:14:"voucher_number";s:5:"23423";s:11:"vendor_name";s:6:"werwrw";s:12:"method_title";s:18:"Training Vssoucher";}` that would be a correct serialized array. I update my answer